# ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0 on OnItemClick of Listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a `cart_layout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:id="@+id/cart_listview"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/whiteBg"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/whiteBg">
        <!-- this layout contains a button and a textview which I don't think is the problem -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the java code for it in `Cart.java` :

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cart_layout);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    dbhandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    product_all = dbhandler.getProduct();
    total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cart_total_textview);

    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.cart_listview);
    
    cart_adapter = new Custom_Cart_Adapter(this,product_all);
    listview.setAdapter(cart_adapter);
    
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.v("ITEM CLICK","CLICKED ITEM POSITION: "+position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Cart.this, Item_edit_details.class);
            intent.putExtra("the_product", product_all.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

I just want to make an OnItemClick event but everytime I tap the item, even when the  `listview.setOnItemClickListener` is there or not, Logcat shows

> ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
>
> ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

and nothing happens.

I also see a strange log like this, sometime it said "true" sometime it said "false":

> ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{3308191 token=android.os.BinderProxy@c7ed098 {com.iwant.namhhgames.newiwant/com.iwant.namhhgames.newiwant.Listing_items}} show : false

I don't know if it related to the problem, and  I have no idea when the problem occurs, maybe after I messed something up.

And the Logcat is shown for real device only. With AVD, there is nothing shown.

Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: same issue here. very stramge

Comment: app freezes also when i click the button

Comment: and when I press back the app unfreeezes.

Comment: same issue here too. Any solutions?

Comment: any solution yet?

Comment: What SDK min and max and version on Android Studio are you guy using? I for this error implementing Facebook Login with an updated app from min sdk=10, target sdk=15, Android Studio 2.2

Comment: You need to post more code, since the parts that are present seem to work fine in Hicham Pirhano's answer. The problem could be that your adapter returns `false` in `isEnabled(int position)` or you have set `listView.setEnabled(false)`  or you set touch listener that returns `true` to your `listview`, or some other view somehow consumes your click.

Comment: I am having this problem, and I am just setting my `Activity` `content view` to an empty `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

this run without issue so maybe your adapter

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.testlist);

        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listest);

        ArrayList<String> cart_adapter = new ArrayList<String>();

        cart_adapter.add("Me");
        cart_adapter.add("Him");
        cart_adapter.add("You");

        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cart_adapter));

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e("ITEM CLICK","CLICKED ITEM POSITION: "+position);
            }
        });

    }
```

> 11-16 14:55:31.735 1915-1915/ca.dti.grounded.app E/ITEM CLICK: CLICKED ITEM POSITION: 2
>   11-16 14:55:34.233 1915-1915/ca.dti.grounded.app E/ITEM CLICK: CLICKED ITEM POSITION: 0
>   11-16 14:55:35.616 1915-1915/ca.dti.grounded.app E/ITEM CLICK: CLICKED ITEM POSITION: 1
>   11-16 14:55:36.061 1915-1915/ca.dti.grounded.app E/ITEM CLICK: CLICKED ITEM POSITION: 2

Answer (score 1):

You don't list Custom_Cart_Adapter.java.
Try to add android:focusable="false" in your single_item.xml which you use inside Custom_Cart_Adapter.java
It can help.

Answer (score 1):

The onItemClickListener from listview should not be used as it can cause many issues as this. For this case, I would suggest the use of a custom click listener on the adapter's view and passing the index through this click listener, I mean, try to implement your own onItemClickListener.

As you may notice, at recyclerView the onItemClickListener doesn't appear and the proper approach is to implement your own onItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

You did right but for `arrayadapter` your `onItemClick()` listener should be look like this.

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listest);
   listview .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
            Log.e("ITEM CLICK","CLICKED ITEM POSITION: "+position);
      }
   });
```

Hope it will help you!!